# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #976: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton

Tags: android

I've got this this app which I'm developing, it perfectly works on android Emulator nexus 5  device, but when I'm trying it out on a real physical device, it crashes!
there are two activities, the first one (the main) has no problem, but there is a button, which I use to go to the next activity, when I click it, the app crashes and goes out!
so I used the USB debugging tool, and here is the Logcat:

```
11-17 13:04:31.898 3096-3096/com.dall.filmanlevel1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dall.filmanlevel1/com.dall.filmanlevel1.FilManInShop}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #976: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #976: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at com.dall.filmanlevel1.FilManInShop.onCreate(FilManInShop.java:35)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.dall.filmanlevel1.FilManInShop.onCreate(FilManInShop.java:35) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02009e a=-1 r=0x7f02009e}
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1967)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3341)
     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:591)
     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
     at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
     at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:51)
     at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:64)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
     at com.dall.filmanlevel1.FilManInShop.onCreate(FilManInShop.java:35) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any kind of help will be appreciated!

here is the `XML` file, thank you guys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:context="com.dall.filmanlevel1.FilManInShop">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="in the shop"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/theScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="I am a doctor at the London hospital. "
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filamnCInshoptt1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/filmanpic1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="I read the writing under the picture."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filamnCInshoptt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tarjomeBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:text="translate" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekVoice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/playStopVoice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_background"
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

</TableRow>
```

the Picture i added is `JPEG` format 350*350 pixels and 25kb in size.

here is the Button_bkackground :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pause_black_48dp" android:state_checked="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_48dp" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

Comment: share your xml layout

Comment: can you add your xml file which related to next activity

Comment: try to add PNG format instead of JPEG

Comment: Please post your "@drawable/toggle_button_background" file as well

Comment: @Reza you are facing this error due to this:
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):
your file is not a drawable but an image. use it as an image in mipmap or create a drawable to give the background.

Comment: @Umair. which file is not a drawable? please explain a little more ...

Comment: @RezaHamzehie can you tell me on which version you are testing the application ?

Comment: @Umair   the mobile phone runs android 4.2.2, and I set my min sdk in Android Manifest to 15.

Comment: @RezaHamzehie add this line in your gradle file.
under android tab. and then check
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: @Umair. which line?

Comment: vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: @Umair    no returns this error: 
 Error:(6, 0) Could not get unknown property 'vectorDrawables' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
<a href="openFile:D:\androidprojects\Level1storiesA\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! thank you guys for providing answers and help.
for other people who may encounter such a thing, the story is I had a toggle Button, and tried to customize it by defining an `Xml` file for its Background. this file `@drawable/toggle_button_background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pause_black_48dp" android:state_checked="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_black_48dp" android:state_checked="false" />
```

The problem was I put that file in the `drawable` folder and totally ignored the `drawable-v21` folder, that's it! what it did just copied the that file into the `drawable-v21` folder as well and then things went smoothly and solved! here  how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add this two in Gradle file (App):

```
'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

I think, its not finding android.widget in your app library. Please include it.

Comment: But I'm using API 25